# meaning of the phrase "moment's thought"?

Tags: meaning

Here it goes in context:

> You should give your body a moment's thought.

It is understandable that it means to pay attention to something, but that sounds weird. Why is it not give something *a moment of thought*? Do those two phrases mean the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sentence means

> You should think for a moment about your body.

When we give something some thought, we think about it.

A **moment's thought** means "the thought of a moment", the thought that transpires in and for a moment.

Compare

> He needed a **day's rest**.
>
> A **month's delay** is unacceptable.
>
> Each ring on the tree represents a **year's growth**.
>
> They went to London for a **fortnight's stay**.

Answer (score 1):

As an addon to Tromano's answer, a quote from a beautiful poem titled "[What is life](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/what-is-life/)?" by John Clare:

> And what is Life? An hour-glass on the run,
>   A mist retreating from the morning sun,
>   A busy, bustling, still-repeated dream.
>   Its length? A minute's pause, **a moment's thought**.
>   And Happiness? A bubble on the stream,
>   That in the act of seizing shrinks to nought.